# How does de-myelination occur in multiple sclerosis?

Tags: genetics, brain, autoimmune

From what I understand, only the oligodendrocytes are affected in multiple sclerosis, and they are attacked by T cells which cross the blood-brain barrier. This leads me to two questions:

1. How is the blood-brain barrier affected in MS that allows T lymphocytes to cross the barrier?
2. Why do the T lymphocytes attack the oligodendroccytes? And when they do, what is the mechanism for de-myelination?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Q2 is likely some kind of autoimmune disorder, which is very difficult to study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-cell migration to the brain is very limited and occurs at a very low level in healthy conditions, however during diseases the number of T cells passing through the blood-brain barrier is elevate due to increased expression of traffic signals and adhesive molecules. 
I've found two good articles on how T-cells migrate through blood-brain barrier:

[J Neural Transm (2006) 113: 477–485
Molecular mechanisms involved in T cell migration across
the blood–brain barrier, B. Engelhardt](http://download-v2.springer.com/static/pdf/451/art%253A10.1007%252Fs00702-005-0409-y.pdf?token2=exp=1427967013~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F451%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs00702-005-0409-y.pdf*~hmac=ce8eb39c0a3ab7c37129d8978921d993895e1a635ddcf7a9d760c05eb0e7e4fb)

and 
 [D. W. Miller, “Immunobiology of the blood-brain barrier.,” J. Neurovirol., vol. 5, no. 6, pp. 570–578, 1999.](http://jneurovirol.com/pdf/5%286%29/570-578.pdf)

During T-cell maturation, those that react too heavily to antigens of the body are killed to avoid having T-cells that would kill the body's own cells. But in rare cases this process fails and auto-reactive T-cell get released from the thymus ([This](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v372/n6501/pdf/372100a0.pdf) short paper is good for starters). So the (simplified) reason why T-cells attack oligodendrocytes is that they falsely recognize them as pathogens, and therefore kill them. The loss of oligodendrocytes results in loss of myelin sheats.

Also in [this](http://brain.oxfordjournals.org/content/122/7/1283) paper (it holds many info on demyelination and multiple sclerosis) it is shown that even non-specicfic T-cells can open the way for antibodies through the blood-brain barried, and this results in extended demyelination.